# verifying data inside tkinter entry box. if its numeric or alpha or an email

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

```
from tkinter import *
import os
te=Tk()
te.geometry('300x200')
L1 = Label(text = "User Name").grid(row=1,column=0)
E1 = Entry( te)
E1.grid(row=1,column=2)
L2 = Label(text="full Name").grid(row=2,column=0)
E2 = Entry( te)
E2.grid(row=2,column=2)
L3 = Label(text="email").grid(row=3,column=0)
E3 = Entry( te)
E3.grid(row=3,column=2)
L4 = Label(text="admission no.").grid(row=4,column=0)
E4 = Entry(te)
E4.grid(row=4,column=2)
def adduser():
    add=open(E1.get(),"a+")
    add.write(E2.get()+":")
    add.write(E3.get()+":")
    add.write(E4.get()+":")
    add.write(E1.get())
    add.close()
    B5.config(state="disabled")
    print('registraion susscefull')
    B6=Button(text="  login  ",command=main)
    B6.grid(row=5,column=1)
def main():
    os.system("main.py")
B5=Button(text="register",command=adduser)
B5.grid(row=5,column=1)
te.mainloop()
```

Hello coders, I need some help with validations in `tkinter` so this is what I need:

1. no space should be in username and at least use of 1 number
2. email id should be checked that @ and .com are used
3. admission number should be only integers
4. full name should be only alphabets

I tried but did not have any success and now you guys are my last hope for this. Please help. I'm still learning and looking forward for your help and code.

Thanks and have a great day.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any attempt at doing validation in your code. Please [edit] the code to show us what you've tried. Also explain if you want the validation to happen as the user types, or if it should happen inside `adduser`. Please be aware that StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, so you may not get anyone willing to write the code for you.

Comment: I suggest you check out python regex. This should help you with the custom input validation you are looking for. 
 https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Comment: Well nothing much here, check for `if '@' not in e3.get() or '.com' not in e3.get(): #do something`.

Comment: @CoolCloud bro how i could set limitation that in name we can only input alphabets . thank it will help i got it just im confused with name section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()

def check(): #function to check 
    if '@' not in e2.get() or '.com' not in e2.get(): #if @ or .com is present
        messagebox.showinfo('Not a valid email address','Enter a valid email address')
    else: #if not show error message
        messagebox.showinfo('Success','Succesfull!')

e2 = Entry(root)
e2.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

b = Button(root,text='Check mail',command=check)
b.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

In this example a simple check is provided to check if it has '@' or '.com' in it.

And, since you asked a way to only allow alphabets, take a look at this simple validation.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()

def validate(inp):
    if inp == "": #to begin typing
        return True
    elif inp.isalpha(): #to only allow alphabets
        return True
    elif ' ' in inp: #to allow space in between
        return True
    else:
        return False #dont allow anything else

vcmd = root.register(validate) #register the function

e = Entry(root,validate='all',validatecommand=(vcmd,'%S')) #now add validating to it
e.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

To understand more better about validation, take a look at Bryan Oakleys answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/interactively-validating-entry-widget-content-in-tkinter)

Comment: thanks brother . really helped me. can u help me with 1 more problem.   actually i want that my pdf should be auto listed in tkinter canvas with 2 button. when ever i add pdf in a folder it should be auto added in tkinter canvas . how i can do this ? looking for your valuable reply

Comment: @anshul Hi, im not sure about how pdf can be integrated with tkinter, but if you have any doubts, make sure to research a bit and then ask a Q here, and people would be delighted to help you out. I also think you need a module that displays pdf, take a read through [here](https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/tkinter-to-make-pdf-fast-and-free-with-text-or-html/)

Comment: thank bro yeah i search online before asking here but i was not able to find good info on web thanks buddy for your kind help .